# UI5 GridLayout content is not setting same height

Tags: javascript, sapui5

i have a view with GridLayout with 2 content one is TreeTable and Another one is Panel

i need to show both content with same height, but my custom control which is inside the Panel is not in same height

View is

```
<mvc:View xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    class="sapUiSizeCompact" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
    xmlns:table="sap.ui.table"
    xmlns:testResp="chiru.controller" 
    height="100%">
    <l:Grid defaultSpan="L10 M10 S10" class="sapUiNoMarginTop sapUiNoMarginBottom sapUiNoMarginBegin sapUiNoMarginEnd">
        <l:content>
            <table:TreeTable 
            selectionMode="MultiToggle"
            enableSelectAll="false"
            rows="{path:'/resources', parameters: {arrayNames:['categories']}}">
                <table:layoutData>
                    <l:GridData span="L2 M2 S2" />
                </table:layoutData>

                <table:columns>
                   <table:Column width="13rem">
                       <Label text="Resources"/>
                       <table:template>
                           <Text text="{name}"/>
                       </table:template>
                   </table:Column>
                </table:columns>
            </table:TreeTable>
            <Panel height="100%">
                <content>
                <testResp:TestResp resources="{/resources}">
                </testResp:TestResp>
                </content>
            </Panel>
        </l:content>
    </l:Grid>
</mvc:View>
```

And my Custom control TestResp is

```
/**
 * 
 */
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/Control",
    "sap/ui/core/HTML"
], function (Control,HTML) {
    "use strict";
    return Control.extend("chiru.controller.TestResp", {
        metadata : {
            properties : {
                width:  {type : "sap.ui.core.CSSSize", defaultValue : "100%"},
                height: {type : "sap.ui.core.CSSSize", defaultValue : "100%"},
                resources : {type : "Array", defaultValue : []},
                demands : {type : "Array", defaultValue : []}
            },
            aggregations : {
                _timeLine : {type : "sap.ui.core.HTML", multiple: false, visibility : "visible"}
            },
            events : {
                change : {
                    parameters : {
                        value : {type : "int"}
                    }
                }
            }
        } ,
        init : function () {
            this.setAggregation("_timeLine", new HTML({
                content : "<svg id="+this.getId()+"--timeLine></svg>"
            }));
        },
        renderer : function (oRM, oControl) {
            oRM.write("<div");
            oRM.writeControlData(oControl);
            oRM.writeClasses();
            oRM.addStyle("height",oControl.getHeight());
            oRM.addStyle("width",oControl.getWidth());
            oRM.writeStyles();
            oRM.write(">");
            oRM.renderControl(oControl.getAggregation("_timeLine"));
            oRM.write("</div>");
        }
    });
});
```

Which look like this

[image]

How to make the both in same height? why Grid layout is not taking same height?
Do i need to use other layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Panel` will only take required space in parent container leaving some empty space, it will not occupy entire available space.

So, to make it forcefully occupy remaining space you need to set it's height explicitly.

Set height of `Panel` with that of `TreeTable`.

View code

```
<table:TreeTable id="table">
```

Consider `oTable` is your `TreeTable` object and `oPanel` is `Panel` object.

```
onAfterRendering: function(){
    var oTable = this.getView().byId("table");
    var tableHeight = $(oTable.getDomRef()).height();
    oPanel.setHeight(tableHeight + "px");
}
```

Comment: onAfterRendering: function() {
   var otable =  this.getView().byId("oTable");
   var tableHeight = $('#'+otable.getId()).height();
      this.getView().byId("oPanel").setHeight(tableHeight+"px");
    } Which gives the grid height not the table height :(

Comment: <table:TreeTable > are you getting this element's height?

Comment: i am not setting the height.. just added to Grid with layoutdata for width.. That why table height is not set

Comment: yes i know you are not specifying height, but once table is rendered the height of table's DOM is avilable

Comment: please check modified answer!